# How to use basic_ostringstream with stateful custom allocator?? (C++11)

Tags: c++, c++11

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream), **std::basic_ostringstream** can be instantiated with a custom allocator. Since C++11, allocators are allowed to have state and my custom allocator class does have internal per-instance state (actually each allocator instance has a pointer to an instance of a **MemPool** class, to which it forwards all allocation requests). This is why my allocator type can't just simply be default-constructed and be expected to work because after all, where is it going to get the address of the **MemPool** instance it's supposed to use from?

Unfortunately, if you take a look at the [constructor prototypes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream/basic_ostringstream) of **std::basic_ostringstream**, you can see that none of the supported constructors actually take an allocator instance! I'm pretty sure that **std::basic_ostringstream** will have to make some allocation(s) to construct its resulting string, and I really want it to use my allocator for those, but how is it going to do that if I have no way of telling it which specific **MemPool** instance to use??

Have I overlooked something here? I feel like I must have but I sure don't see how at the moment.

Comment: Sounds like [LWG 2210](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2210) missed a few

Comment: @Cubbi: Since it seems that this is indeed just an oversight in the C++ standards specification, why don't you post your comment as an actual answer so I can mark it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible that the resolution to the [LWG defect #2210](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2210), which added allocator instances to the constructors of many standard library containers, was not sufficiently thorough and the streams were overlooked. Or perhaps it wasn't clear enough how to approach them. I would suggest filing a new library defect report (or perhaps asking first in [std-discussion](http://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/group/std-discussion/topics))

Comment: I've filed a defect report as you suggested -> http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2429

Comment: LWG DR 2210 is clearly about allocator-aware containers (it says so in the title!) so was never meant to cover `basic_stringstream` which is defined in a completely different clause

Comment: Looks like this will be fixed in c++20l that is, there is a std::basic_ostringstream constructor that can take an allocator object.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a `basic_string<C, T, A>` object to the constructor, and I expect all implementations will copy the allocator from that string object (probably via a call to `allocator_traits<A>::select_on_container_copy_construction()`) but that isn't clearly specified by the standard, and probably should be.

Comment: Hmm, I hadn't thought of that at all. That's actually a very nice workaround (if it really works ... I haven't tried it out yet)!

Comment: Here is a shim until c++20, based on this answer: `template<class C, class T=std::char_traits<C>, class A=std::allocator<C>> struct basic_ostringstream_from_allocator_object : public std::basic_ostringstream<C,T,A> { basic_ostringstream_from_allocator_object(const A &a) : std::basic_ostringstream<C,T,A>( std::basic_string<C,T,A>(a)) {} };`